# Click Event Handler of ASP.Net Button in User Control is not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, event-handling

My User Control in my ASP.Net application has a Button named button. I've added a click event to it like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (!IsPostBack) {
        button.Click += (object o, EventArgs ea) => {
            Response.Redirect("~/Post.aspx?type=" + Type + "&id=" + PostID);
        };
    }
}
```

But whenever I click on the Button it does nothing but reloads the page. What is the problem with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `if (!IsPostBack)` condition to set the event handler on every postback:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    button.Click += (object o, EventArgs ea) => {
        Response.Redirect("~/Post.aspx?type=" + Type + "&id=" + PostID);
    };
}
```